# Solving $(x^2 +1)y''+2xy=0, y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$ by power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have to resolve this differential equation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2 +1)y''+2xy=0, \hspace{1cm}y(0)=1, y'(0)=1
\end{eqnarray*}
by power series. So I know that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
y&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}x^{n}\\
y'&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_{n}x^{n-1}\\
y''&=& \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_{n}x^{n-2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2 +1)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_{n}x^{n-2}+2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}x^{n}&=&0\\
 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_{n}x^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2c_{n}x^{n+1}&=&0\\
\end{eqnarray*}
So I do the substitution $k=n-2$ and $k=n+1$ and I have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)c_{k}x^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}x^{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2c_{k-1}x^{k}&=&0\\
2c_{2}+6c_{3}x+2c_{0}x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[k(k-1)c_{k}+(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}+2c_{k-1}]x^{k}&=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
But in general:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 k(k-1)c_{k}+(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}+2c_{k-1}=0
\end{eqnarray*}
And I don't know how can I continue, Cause I can't find $c_{1}$ and in general I don't know how can I write $c_{k}$. I'm stuck. Do you know how can I continue? Can you give some hint to continue? Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the effort.

Comment: Unfortunately this DE has no solution with elementary function...https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2+%2B1%29y%27%27%2B2xy%3D0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2c_{2}+6c_{3}x+2c_{0}x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}[k(k-1)c_{k}+(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}+2c_{k-1}]x^{k}=0$$

This means that:
$$c_2=0  \text { and }
3c_3=-c_0$$
Now for $k=2$ you have :
$$[2c_{2}+4(2+1)c_{4}+2c_{1}]=0$$
$$  \implies  6c_{4}=-c_{1}$$
$$....$$

---

And as  @SammyBlack  commented you have the initial condition $y'(0)=1 \implies c_1=1$ and $y(0)=1  \implies c_0=1$.

Comment: And $c_1=1$ from the initial condition $y’(0)=1$.

Comment: You're right I didnt notice the initial condition Thanks  @SammyBlack

Comment: Sorry I have a question, when I used your answer I have this: $c_{2}=0, 3c_{3} = -c_{0}, 6c_{4}=-c_{1}, 20c_{5}= -6c_{0}, 30 c_{6} = -\frac{2}{3} c_{0} + 2 c_{1}...$ but I can't find the recurrence.. Do you know some way find it?

Comment: You should get $$y(x)=1-\dfrac 13 x^3-\dfrac 16 x^4 +........$$  @ANGIEDUQUEOROZCO

Comment: Not easy to find the pattern if there is one @ANGIEDUQUEOROZCO

Comment: @user2715281 thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2 +1)y''+2xy=0, \hspace{1cm}y(0)=1, y'(0)=1
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Here is another approach to find the series solution.

$$y=y(0) +y'(0)x + 1/2 y"(0)x^2 + 1/6  y'''(0)x^3 +......$$
From $$
(x^2 +1)y''+2xy=0, $$ we get $y''(0)=0$

Upon differentiation we have $$ 2xy''+(x^2+1)y''' +2y+2xy'=0$$
Thus $y'''(0)=-2$

Continue this process and you will get the pattern